# g++ binary file dosent work ( /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6 not found)

Tags: g++, cross-compiling, embedded-linux, libstdc++

I use C library and my previous C files in new my C++ codes by use Include CHEADER and at end , I compile it with arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ . After copy binary file to embedded device ,it dosen't work and show message:

```
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6: version 'CXXABI_1.3.9' not found  
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6: version 'GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found
```

Comment: Perhaps you have an older version of libstdc++.so.6 on your device? Just a guess.

Comment: How can I fix it?

Comment: Your device. Upgrade its software. I would have no idea how to. Perhaps copy the newer version over from your development machine?

Comment: sudo apt-get upgrade
No result.

Comment: Maybe your linux version on the device has older version of libstdc++.so.6 then your development machine. Maybe the correct version of libstdc++.so.6 is not where your executable is trying to find it. Debug it. I can't, I don't have the device.